# Rejoin the cluster after restart embedded vertx application

Tags: playframework-2.2, vert.x

I have an embedded vertx application under play 2.2. After I restart the play app, the embedded won't join back to the cluster again. I can only see this message from vertx command line application but not joining as a member.

```
[192.168.133.141]:5701 [dev] 39999 accepted socket connection from /192.168.133.141:5702
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn't set the cluster.xml correctly in the play embedded vertx. I made a repo to demo the play embedded vertx and vertx instance. Feel free to test and report bugs.

https://github.com/peer-im/vertx-cluster-with-play